# Perl regex in Nagios check

Tags: linux, perl, nagios

I am unfamiliar with perl, and I have a need to modify a Nagios check. I'd appreciate any advice on how to proceed. The check I'm using is check_smart, found here:

https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/nagios-plugins/check_smart.php

This script lets you check SMART values from hard drives and present the results in a simple form for monitoring. As it stands, the script can take a regex in the form /dev/sd[a-c] for one of the options; I believe that this is the section which allows this:

```
        # list of devices for a loop
    my(@dev);

    if ( $opt_d ){
        # normal mode - push opt_d on the list of devices
        push(@dev,$opt_d);
    } else {
        # glob all devices - try '?' first 
        @dev =glob($opt_g);
    }

    foreach my $opt_dl (@dev){
        warn "Found $opt_dl\n" if $opt_debug;
        if (-b $opt_dl || -c $opt_dl){
            $device .= $opt_dl.":";

        } else {
            warn "$opt_dl is not a valid block/character special device!\n\n" if $opt_debug;
        }
    }
```

I don't quite understand why the variable is $opt_dl when earlier it seems to be $opt_d. The result, however, is that the script returns something like:
OK: [/dev/sda] - Device is clean --- [/dev/sdb] - Device is clean --- [/dev/sdc] - Device is clean

EDIT: Here's the code where $opt_d is set; on further thought it seems like $opt_dl is just $opt_d while it's in a loop or something?

```
use vars qw($opt_b $opt_d $opt_g $opt_debug $opt_h $opt_i $opt_v);
Getopt::Long::Configure('bundling');
GetOptions(
                      "debug"       => \$opt_debug,
    "b=i" => \$opt_b, "bad=i"       => \$opt_b,
    "d=s" => \$opt_d, "device=s"    => \$opt_d,
    "g=s" => \$opt_g, "global=s"    => \$opt_g,
    "h"   => \$opt_h, "help"        => \$opt_h,
    "i=s" => \$opt_i, "interface=s" => \$opt_i,
    "v"   => \$opt_v, "version"     => \$opt_v,
);
```

The part of the code I'd like to change in a similar fashion is:

```
        # Allow all device types currently supported by smartctl
    # See http://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Supported_RAID-Controllers
    if ($opt_i =~ m/(ata|scsi|3ware|areca|hpt|cciss|megaraid|sat)/) {
            $interface = $opt_i;
    } else {
            print "invalid interface $opt_i for $opt_d!\n\n";
            print_help();
            exit $ERRORS{'UNKNOWN'};
    }
```

Specifically, I'd like to be able to pass the script something like "megaraid,[5-8]" and let it run for each. In this case, I would not be passing the regex for the device, it would just be /dev/sda.

If anyone could give me advice on this I'd appreciate it!

Comment: It's hard to comment about `$opt_d` without seeing the code that sets it.  `$opt_dl` is being used for iterating through the `@dev` array, which I guess holds the list of devices.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have edited the post to show how $opt_d is set.

Answer (score 1):

`$opt_dl` is probably poorly named and has nothing to do with your `$opt_d`, those are two separate variables.

From the `if` statement, if `$opt_d` is not set (that is the script was not given any device name to act upon), then `glob` is called with the value of `$opt_g` and it is `glob` in fact that finds out all filenames based on the regex given inside `$opt_g`.

After this `if` statement, the `@dev` array is filed with the names of devices to handle.

And then you have a `foreach` statement which means a loop on each item inside the `@dev` array. And during the loop, each item is in the `$opt_dl` variable, due to its use on the `foreach` statement.

However I was not able to understand what you wanted to do in your last paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will read up on using 'glob'. What I meant in the last paragraph is that the current script works with a regex when you pass it the variable for the drives (/dev/sd[a-c]), and what I would like is for it to perform a similar loop through the variable for the RAID card (megaraid,[5-8]); they are both essentially doing the same thing, just in the case of the RAID card the drives are behind the card so don't appear as separate devices.

Comment: If you pass the script the string "megaraid,[5-8]" what should it computes from it, what are each item of the loop? Where/How is used the variabble for the RAID card?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the maintainer of check_smart and it's funny I accidentally stumbled on that question now.

> I don't quite understand why the variable is $opt_dl when earlier it seems to be $opt_d. The result, however, is that the script returns something like: OK: [/dev/sda] - Device is clean --- [/dev/sdb] - Device is clean --- [/dev/sdc] - Device is clean

So basically when you use the `-g` parameter, you tell the check_smart plugin to use glob (https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) - this is not the same as regular expression. The drives matching the glob expression (e.g. `-d '/dev/sd[a-z]`) will create a list (`$opt_dl`) and the plugin will run through each drive in a for loop.

> Specifically, I'd like to be able to pass the script something like "megaraid,[5-8]" and let it run for each. In this case, I would not be passing the regex for the device, it would just be /dev/sda.

This is already possible since release 5.0 (which was released in April 2014, way before your question ;-) ). You just need to change the syntax. Instead of using the glob expression on `-d`, you use it on the interface parameter (`-i`). Practical example: `-i 'megaraid,[5-8]'`.

Since the newest release (6.6, released a couple of days ago), the output for multiple drive checks (using `-g`) and hardware storage/raid controllers has slightly changed and now indicates the interface's device id rather than the logical drive path:

```
# ./check_smart.pl -g /dev/sda -i 'megaraid,[1-3]'
OK: [megaraid,1] - Device is clean --- [megaraid,2] - Device is clean --- [megaraid,3] - Device is clean|
```

This is all described in the official documentation, too.

More info: 
https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/monitoring-plugins/check_smart.php
https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/914/check_smart-6.6-multiple-drives-check-megaraid-3ware-cciss-controllers

I hope this answers your question, although I am probably 2 years late.